# Closing a file without a reference to it

Tags: python, file-io, cpython, pypy

Running this in CPython:

```
content = open('test', 'r').read()
```

does not leave the file open, since the file object is automatically garbage collected (and therefore closed) when it doesn't have a reference.

Since this is an implementation detail of CPython and relies on reference counting, this code will leak file descriptors on other implementations, such as PyPy.

My question: is there a way to ensure a file is closed without using the `with` statement or explicitly calling its `close()` method?

Comment: Your question is like "how to eat a soup without a spoon". Can you explain the reasons why yon can't use `with` or `close`?

Comment: It's more like "*can* I eat soup without a spoon?". I can use those, of course, I'm just curious as to whether I *have* to if I want my code to be correct when run on not-CPython. There is a certain elegance to, for example, doing all your file operation inside one loop comprehension - which seems to be impossible in eg PyPy.

Comment: Also, *of course* you can eat soup without a spoon.

Comment: The file will eventually get closed in PyPy, on either a garbage collection or program termination.  Are you looking for a more timely, deterministic method of ensuring your file gets closed?

Comment: Yeah. Something like `contextlib`'s `closing` method, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and say that no, it's impossible to make sure a file object gets closed without a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not get why you want to avoid using the `with`-statement, but probably it would help to define a function to wrap your file IO:

```
def read_data_from_file(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        return f.read()
```

It's clear, it does what it's supposed to do, and it can be used inside a list comprehension.

If you want to iterate the lines with a "throw-away" file handle, why not introduce a wrapper (generator) function like this:

```
def iterate_lines_from_file(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line
```

It's super-easy to use:

```
processed = [process_line(line) for line in iterate_lines_from_file("filename")]
```

Comment: I was looking for a built-in way of making sure the file is closed. My use case is iterating over an `open(file, 'r')` without keeping a reference to the file object. It's no problem when used inside small methods in CPython, but it's going to leak file descriptors in other implementations.

Comment: @RomanLevin Could you please clarify how you implement the iteration that it disables you to use the `with` stmt?

Comment: For example `lines = [line for line in open('file', 'r')]`. You could do this with a `with`, of course.